# No inference in Generic Callback JavaFX

Tags: java, generics, javafx, callback

I have a `TextFieldTableCell<Item,String>` that I need to validate, therefore I can't use the usual way of

```
column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

So my intention was to do something like

```
column.setCellFactory(param -> {
    TableCell<Item,String> cell = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn().call(params);
    validate(validationRules, cell);
});
```

However it says that

```
CallbackTableColumn<Object,String>,TableCell<Object,String> cannot be 
applied to TableColumn<Item,String>
```

I get that, what I don't get is should it infer the type instead of `Object`

The only workaround I've found is to define a new `StringConverter<String>` which seems a little obnoxious.

```
new StringConverter<String>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(String object) {
                return object;
            }

            @Override
            public String fromString(String string) {
                return string;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you can still use TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(). In your on setOnEditCommit you should be able to validate your data then.

Comment: That's right, but the validation should start before starting edit

Comment: Why not `TableCell<Item, String> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>();` though?

Comment: @James_D beacuse that constructor has a `null` `StringConverter` and I would have to implement one for converting strings to strings

Comment: OK, but there is a constructor that takes a converter too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chaining the two method calls (`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` and `call()`), you don't ever specify the actual type of the return of the first method, so the compiler doesn't have a chance to infer the type that should be returned from that method call.

If you want the compiler to infer this, you could do

```
Callback<TableColumn<Item, String>, TableCell<Item, String>> callback = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn();
TableCell<Item, String> cell = callback.call(param);
```

Of course, this is far more verbose than just specifying the type to the generic method [`forTableColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn--) directly:

```
TableCell<Item, String> cell = TextFieldTableCell.<Item>forTableColumn().call(param);
```

All of this seems a bit artificial, though. You are implementing a callback, and since `TextFieldTableCell` has appropriate constructors available, there is no need to go through an intermediate `Callback`. You can just do:

```
column.setCellFactory(col -> {
    TextFieldTableCell<Item, String> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>();
    validate(validationRules, cell);
    return cell ;
});
```

or, if you need to specify a converter:

```
StringConverter<String> converter =  ... ;
column.setCellFactory(col -> {
    TextFieldTableCell<Item, String> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>(converter);
    validate(validationRules, cell);
    return cell ;
});
```

For a default converter, you can just use

```
TextFieldTableCell<Item, String> cell = 
    new TextFieldTableCell<>(TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER);
```

Comment: When instantiating the `TableCell` with the empty constructor the converter is null, that is why I started looking for an alternative

Comment: So can you not instantiate with the other constructor?

Comment: Yeah but then I'd have to do a Converter from string to string, Question Updated

Comment: Wow, I looked for something like that but couldn't find it thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to implicitly specify *column type* used in call to `forTableColumn()`:

```
TableCell<Item,String> cell = TextFieldTableCell.<Item>forTableColumn().call(param);
```

If you will look at `forTableColumn()` [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn--), you'll see that it depends on generic type `S` which is type of elements in your `TableView`. If not specified, `Object` type is used which causes problems when you try to assign it to `TableCell<Item,String> cell`.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain more into how? and why?

Comment: You need to specify both types in `ComboBoxTableCell`: `ComboBoxTableCell.<Item, String>forTableColumn()`

Comment: Just amended my answer with explanation.